# Type '{ store: MockStoreEnhanced<unknown, {}>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick[...]

Tags: typescript, react-redux, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test for a container in typescript.

According to multiple answers, I am supposed to use a mock store, and give it to the container using the store attribute, which always exists. This seems to work only in javascript though:

```
import React from "react";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import DashboardChooserContainer from "../../src/dashboard/DashboardChooserContainer";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";


describe("/dashboard/DashboardChooserContainer", () => {
  const mockStore = configureMockStore();
  const store = mockStore(
    {}
  );
    const renderedComponent = shallow(<DashboardChooserContainer store={store}/>);
  
  it("some test will go here", () => {
    expect(
      renderedComponent.contains("a")
    ).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

However I got the following error on the line `const renderedComponent = shallow(<DashboardChooserContainer store={store}/>);` for the `store=` part:

```
Type '{ store: MockStoreEnhanced<unknown, {}>; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<unknown, never>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<unknown, never>, never> & Pick<InferProps<unknown>, never>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ... 2 more ... & Partial<...>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ... 2 more ... & Partial<...>)'.
  Property 'store' does not exist on type '(IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<unknown, never>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<unknown, never>, never> & Pick<InferProps<unknown>, never>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ... 2 more ... & Partial<...>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ... 2 more ... & Partial<...>)'.ts(2322)
```

Actually - as I am just trying to bootstrap the project - at this point DashboardChooserContainer does not have any property:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import DashboardChooserUI from "dashboard/DashboardChooserUI";
import { GlobalState } from "GlobalState"

type ReduxDispatch = CallableFunction;
interface IDashboardProps {
}

function mapStateToProps(state:GlobalState):IDashboardProps {
  return {};
}

interface IRegistrationActionProps {
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch:ReduxDispatch):IRegistrationActionProps {
  return {};
}


export default connect<IDashboardProps, IRegistrationActionProps, {}, GlobalState>(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardChooserUI);
```

DashboardChooseUI:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import DashboardUI from "./DashboardUI";


export default class DashboardChooserUI extends React.Component<{},{}> {

  render () {
    return <DashboardUI/>
  }
}
```

My goal now is to write enough tests for `DashboardChooserContainer` so it is fully covered.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to wrap it to a `<Provider>`. I have no idea why, though.

```
const renderedComponent = mount(
  <Provider store={mockStore()}>
    <DashboardChooserContainer />
  </Provider>,
);
```